# What is the R function which creates a ggplot2 graph using largest value for each variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

What can I write in R to create a line graph visualisation (using ggplot2) for the total number of cases per day (essentially plotting points asterisked for each day)?

```
  city    | date  | cases  | cumulative cases (by date) 
----------|-------|--------|------------------------
  London  | Day 1 |   4    |            4 
  Paris   | Day 1 |   5    |            9 
  Madrid  | Day 1 |   3    |            12 *
  London  | Day 2 |   6    |            6
  Paris   | Day 2 |   3    |            9 
  Madrid  | Day 2 |   8    |            17 *
  London  | Day 3 |   9    |            9
  Paris   | Day 3 |   7    |            16
  Madrid  | Day 3 |   5    |            21 *
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach grouping by `date` to obtain the max value and then plot. Here the code using `tidyverse` functions:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
#Code
df %>% group_by(date) %>%
  filter(`cumulative cases`==max(`cumulative cases`,na.rm=T)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=date,y=`cumulative cases`,group=1))+
  geom_point(color='purple')+geom_line(color='purple')
```

Output:

[image]

Or adding limits:

```
#Code 2
df %>% group_by(date) %>%
  filter(`cumulative cases`==max(`cumulative cases`,na.rm=T)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=date,y=`cumulative cases`,group=1))+
  geom_point(color='purple')+geom_line(color='purple')+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,21))
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(city = c("London", "Paris", "Madrid", "London", 
"Paris", "Madrid", "London", "Paris", "Madrid"), date = c("Day 1", 
"Day 1", "Day 1", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 3", "Day 3", 
"Day 3"), cases = c(4, 5, 3, 6, 3, 8, 9, 7, 5), `cumulative cases` = c(4, 
9, 12, 6, 9, 17, 9, 16, 21)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for your answer. One question though - why have you added "group = 1" as an argument of ggplot(aes()) ? What does it do?

Comment: @Karima Hi dear. That option enables you to have a one line style plot. Otherwise without that you could get weird behavior on how the line is plotted. As you mentioned one line, I added that option. I hope that was clear enough for you!